# Variable height horizontal accordion

Tags: jquery, html, css, sass

I't trying to build a horizontal accordion design for a client, but I have run into some problems.

The accordion itself works, but the height of the accordion is not correct due to the content inside of it being 'squished' if I change the width of the container.

https://codepen.io/thieukevdb/pen/JajVWW

```
.content {
    flex: 1 0 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 0px;
    transition: .375s ease-in-out;

    &.active {
        max-width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Is there anyone here who can help me with my problem?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the issue you are facing?

Comment: Try `.content{white-space:nowrap;}`  Hope this help

Comment: @thebrownkid the height of the accordion should be the height of the content when a single tab is open. Right now, when the container is closed the text within it is squished, and because of this increasing the height of the container. The text should not be squished and just fade away behind the other tabs

Answer (score 0):

you may want to fix height, and use overflow-y:hidden

```
.content {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: hidden ;
  max-width: 0px;
  transition: .375s ease-in-out;

  &.active {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Please let me know if it helps.

Edit: In case you prefer not to hardcode height, you may hide the content behind the tab and make it visible when active with code as below:

```
.content {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 0px;
  transition: .375s ease-in-out;
  display:none;

  &.active {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Comment: I am fixing height as 100px, but you may play with it as per you requirement

Comment: Fixing the height is not what I want though, the content is variable.

Comment: But for consistent experience, would you not want your tabs to be of same size(height)?

Comment: Yes, I want the tabs to be the same height, but because I don't know what content the client will be inputting in the field, I don't want to set a specific height for the accordion.

Comment: @Mathijsvdb I have updated my answer to meet your requirments